# Get current date and time, using c# for ms access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I can only find out how to get current date, not the combination of current date and time. I haven't found any fitting solution.

```
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Table] (DATE) VALUES (@date)";

 var pDate = new OleDbParameter("@date", SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset);
            pDate.Value = DateTime.Now.Date; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pDate);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT: Also tried:**

```
var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
```

But I'm still just receiving the date"6/12/2016", not the time.

Comment: Well `DateTime.Now` gives you the current date and time - why are you using the `Date` property if you don't want just the date part? And what's the type of the `DATE` field?

Comment: @MattRowland: I think that question is asking for the opposite of this question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah I see that now.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm getting "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." if I only use `DateTime.Now`. Btw you mean in `DATE`-field in db? It's Date/Time.

Comment: @Nyprez: If the type is date/time, why are you using `SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset`? And why are you using `SqlDbType` for an `OleDbParameter`? It sounds like you want `OleDbType.DBTimeStamp`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh I see I used sql server before, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access SQL supports a function named `Now()` which returns the current date and time.

So it would be simpler to let the db engine use `Now()` instead of deriving the equivalent value in c# and then feeding that value to your `INSERT` as a parameter.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Table] ([DATE]) VALUES (Now())";
```

Note `Date` is a [Jet reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#D).  Enclose that name in square brackets in the `INSERT` to signal the db engine you mean an object name instead of the `Date()` function.

Comment: Thanks! Works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a data type known to Access:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Table] (DATE) VALUES (@date)";

var pDate = new OleDbParameter("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            pDate.Value = DateTime.Now; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pDate);
```